# ClassNotFoundException using zxing4processing, Processing Library

Tags: java, processing, qr-code, classnotfoundexception

I am attempting to run the example sketch (generateQRCode) provided by the [zxing4processing – Processing Library](http://cagewebdev.com/index.php/tag/zxing4processing/).

```
import com.aos.zxing4processing.*;
ZXING4P zxing;
zxing = new ZXING4P(this);
```

The following error occurrs at:

```
zxing = new ZXING4P(this);
```

results in `ClassNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.ReaderException` in Processing 2.2.1

I have imported the library correctly, and the only class is ZXING4P.class, located in libraries\com\aos\zxing4processing. I have also tried older versions of Processing.

Any further suggstions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add three jars provided in the [.zip download](http://cagewebdev.com/index.php/tag/zxing4processing/) to your build path.

`zxing4processing.jar`, `zxingcore.jar` and `zxingjavase.jar`

As you can see in the below image, `com.google.zxing.ReaderException.class` is provided in `zxingcore.jar`:

[image]